# Вопрос про изображения и его нажатии

Tags: java

Создаю приложение где много фото(50+). Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии каждого из них открывалось окно с прозрачным фоном, с увеличенным изображением на которую нажали. Или хоть, как сделать например, есть ImageView на другом окне и чтобы там появлялся нажатое нами изображение? Загружаю фото из сети с помощью Picasso.

Comment: Нужно для ImageView передавать новый Image. А лучше всего панель очищать совсем, на которой изображение лежит

Comment: я это знаю, как это делать?